# Sufficient condition such that the set of zeros of an analytic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ contains only isolated points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Consider a real- analytic function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}$. We know that zeros of $f$, roughly speaking, live in the low dimensional manifolds.

**My question:** Does a  'reasonable' sufficient condition exist with which we can check if the zeros of $f$ are a set of isolated points (zero-dimensional manifold)?

Comment: It is trivial that a continuous function on $\mathbb R^n$ has a non-empty zero set made of isolated points only, iff  either $f$ or $-f$ has minimum value $0$  and all its (global) minimum points are strict (i.e. isolated). For an analytic function and a point x , being a strict minimum is an information contained in its Taylor series at x, but it may be quite complicate to obtain (in case of principal homogeneous components that are non-negative yet not positive-definite)

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks. My background is engineer not math. But this totally makes sense now.  Regarding your comment about Taylor series: Can one check the directional derivative at $x$? In particular, if directional derivative is not zero for all direction then we have an isolated zero.

Comment: [in the first comment, $n\ge2$ of course] For a differentiable function, all directional derivatives are zero on a minimum...  You need to look at higher order differentials

Comment: @PietroMajer, Could you give me a few pointers on how to go about these higher-order differentials and which order to choose?

Comment: The Taylor series of $f$ at a point, say the origin, is a series $p_0+p_1+p_2+\dots$ of homogeneous polynomials $p_k$ of degree $k$ (deduced by the $k$-th differentials of $f$  at $x_0$). To tell if $0$ is a minimum point, you look at the lower  positive-degree non-zero term $p_n$. If $n$ is even and $p_n$ only vanishes at $0$, then $0$ is a (strict) local min because $f(x)=p_n(x)+o(\|x\|^n)$. If $n$ is odd, certainly not. If $n$ is even, but $p_n$ has a non-zero kernel $V_n$, then you can't conclude and have to check the contribution of $p_{n+1}$ locally at $V_n$, and so on. It may be a mess.

Comment: @PietroMajer perhaps consider adding an answer. up to you though.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function for which the zero locus $Z=\{f=0\}$ is of dimension at most $n-2$. Then the open set $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus Z$ is connected, and hence path connected. This implies that $f$ is either always positive or always negative on $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus Z$ because otherwise there would exist a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n\setminus Z$ for which $f(\gamma(0))<0$ and $f(\gamma(1))>0$. But then, by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ should vanish at a point on $\gamma$, a contradiction. We deduce that $f$ is either always non-positive or always non-negative.

**Update)** Maybe the answer was not completely clear. I argued that if zeros are isolated (or even lie on a submanifold of codimension larger than one), then either $\forall \mathbf{x}\, f(\mathbf{x})\geq 0$ or $\forall \mathbf{x}\, f(\mathbf{x})\leq 0$. The OP asked about a "reasonable" sufficient condition. Any such condition should involve or imply $f\geq 0$ or $f\leq 0$ by the argument above. But these conditions on their own are not sufficient as pointed out in comments. One way to make them so is by assuming that the Hessian matrix $H(f)$ is always non-degenerate. Because then the local optima (including points where $f=0$) should be isolated. All in all:

1. necessary condition: $f$ does not attain both positive and negative values;
2. sufficient condition: $f$ does not attain both positive and negative values, and $H(f)$ is always non-degenerate.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I could follow what is the point. Thanks

Comment: The question was about SUFFICIENT condition of isolated zeros. Function $(x,y)\mapsto x^2$ is non-negative but the zeros are not isolated.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you for your comment, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what you mean $H(f)$ non-degenerate.  Typically the hessian is another function $g(x) = H(f)(x)$.  Do we want this matrix to be full rank for all $x$ or maybe almost surely $x$?  I also couldn't follow  what local optima have to do with zero of this function.  Can you clarify this too? Thank you again.

Comment: @Boby I want $H(f)$ to be non-degenerate at every single point. If $f\geq 0$ (resp. $f\leq 0$) then any point where $f=0$ is a local minimum (resp. a local maximum).

Comment: ok. I understand now.  It's because if zeros are isolated they are also local optima.